# How to check if jsf component is valid in xhtml

Tags: jsf, twitter-bootstrap-3, jstl

I am using bootstrap css to make a simple form that is a forgot password reminder. If the password does not validate, it will display the error and highlight the input accordingly. Problem is that when I first load the page it is saying the username is already invalid. How do I fix this?

```
<h:form id="forgotPassword" styleClass="mar-top30 mar-bot30">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                            <h3>Password reminder</h3>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg #{!username.valid ? 'has-error' : 'none'}  mar-top15 mar-bot15">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                </span>
                                <h:inputText id="username" value="#{viewAccount.username}" styleClass="form-control input-lg" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your username" p:placeholder="Username">
                                    <f:validateLength maximum="20" minimum="3" />
                                    <f:validator validatorId="forgotPasswordValidator"/>
                                </h:inputText>
                            </div>
                            <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{username.valid}" styleClass="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h:message for="username"/>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Send Reset Link" action="#{viewAccount.forgotPassword()}" styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block" />
                            <h:link outcome="login" styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block mar-top15"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Return to login</h:link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </h:form>
```

Comment: Where is it printing the message on the page ? Can you post your username bean

Comment: I have a viewAccount bean, i was under the assumption that the component id "username" is binded to the inputText id="username" automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add binding to username and use it to check if component is valid or alternatively,

Add a method to an application bean and use it in UI

```
public static boolean isValid(String clientId) {
        UIComponent comp = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                    getViewRoot().findComponent(clientId);
        if(comp instanceof UIInput) {
            return ((UIInput)comp).isValid();
        }
        throw new IllegalAccessError();
    }
```

And in the UI

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block"
          rendered="#{facesUtil.isValid('forgotPassword:username')}" 
          styleClass="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
  <button type="button" class="close" 
            data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
 <h:message for="username"/>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: would it also be possible just to use the binding="#{username}" option on the h:inputText? or does that have a different effect?

Comment: Yes , you can use binding="#{username}" as well . I was just throwing another idea where you don't have to add binding in beans if you have several inputs.

Comment: Wouldn't the static of `isValid` be `thead` unsafe, causing problems if a lot of users were accessing the site?